# My True or False function is working but how do I alternate the rows with consistent spacing in the True statement?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, spacing

I have tried rearranging the code around and I am very close to figuring this out but in my True statement the results are close to aliging correctly but I can't figure it out. This homework assignment requires that the rows alternate with a space if True but if False they must form a square.

My code:

```
def get_brick_pattern(max_rows=1, max_cols=1, running_bond=True or False):
    brick = ""
    result = ""
    columns = max_cols
    rows = max_rows
    if running_bond is True:
        for rows in range(max_rows):
            for columns in range(max_cols):
                if (rows) % 2 == 0:
                    result += brick
                else:
                    result += " " + brick
            result += "\n"
        return result
    elif running_bond is False:
        for rows in range(1, max_rows+1):
            for columns in range(1, max_cols+1):
                result += brick
            result += "\n"
        return result

print(get_brick_pattern(3, 6, True))---for testing
```

The results are supposed look like just as an example:

My current output for the True statment looks like this:

Comment: You need to explain what this is supposed to do.

Comment: The parameter definition `running_bond=True or False` doesn't make sense. Since `True or False` is `True` this boils down to `running_bond=True`. Did you want to make a type hint?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add a space before each brick in the inner loop, just at the beginning of the line. Move the `if rows % 2 == 0:` check to the outer loop.

Then you don't need the inner loop at all, since you can use `*` to repeat a string N times.

```
        for rows in range(max_rows):
            if row % 2 == 1:
                result += " "
            result += brick * max_cols
            result += "\n"
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... the rows alternate with a space if True but if False they must form a square ..."*

Check *rows % 2* before the *inner-loop*.

```py
for rows in range(max_rows):
    if (rows) % 2: result += ' '
    for columns in range(max_cols):
        result += brick
    result += "\n"
```

Output, for *3, 6*.